# What is the canonical way to clone an SVGMatrix?

Tags: javascript, dom, browser, svg

Given an SVGMatrix m, what is the canonical way to retrieve an independent copy of the matrix?

Of course, `m.scale(1)` is a possible way, but I am wondering whether there is something more idiomatic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create another SVG matrix using [createSVGMatrix](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#__svg__SVGSVGElement__createSVGMatrix) 
then just copy each element from one matrix to another

```
dest.a = source.a;
dest.b = source.b;
dest.c = source.c;
```

etc. The work-in-progress SVG 2 specification has some proposals to make this less tedious.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the proposals in the work-in-progress SVG 2 specification you were talking about?

As to your solution: That a new matrix is created is certainly more explicit in your solution; the disadvantage, however, is that it takes seven statements, not just one statement.

Comment: The published SVG 2 draft has not been updated with those changes. You'd have to build your own specification document from the documentation source code per: http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/WG/wiki/SVG2/Authoring_Guide You can always create your own function wrap do matrix copying.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the documentation source code, which contains those changes. (Unfortunately, I have found as well that the rotateFromVector method is still useless because the restriction that x and y both have to be non-zero is still in there, which, also mathematically, does not make much sense.)

Comment: I have accepted your answer as there seem to be no better way and because it points to what will be possible in the future.